# sed to remove certain spaces in the middle

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

I have a text file like this:

```
    6.2341   -0.4024   -2.0936 Cl  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0.1148   -3.7525    1.0392 S   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   -2.5441   -0.8745    1.3714 F   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

The format is: columns 1 to 10, 11 to 20, 21 to 30 are x,y,z coordinates in (10.4) format, i.e. length=10, 4 digits after the decimal point; column 31 is always a space; columns 32 to 32 are the atom type; the remaining columns are not important.

However, for some unknown reason, the atom type field is right-shifted by two columns, like this:

```
    6.2341   -0.4024   -2.0936   Cl  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0.1148   -3.7525    1.0392   S   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   -2.5441   -0.8745    1.3714   F   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

How to use the sed command and regular expression to match these lines and delete the two extra spaces?

Comment: Why do you need to use sed? Why do you need to use regular expressions?

Answer (score 0):

`sed -r 's/(.{30})  /\1/'` will do the trick.

Group the first 30 characters, match two additional spaces, replace the whole with the grouped characters.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using neither sed nor regular expressions you can just use `cut` to remove the 2 offending characters:

```
$ cut --complement -c31,32 file
    6.2341   -0.4024   -2.0936 Cl  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0.1148   -3.7525    1.0392 S   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   -2.5441   -0.8745    1.3714 F   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```